# Jest + Next/Dynamic is throwing not supported error

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, jestjs, next.js

I am facing this error when writing test for my component which has:

```
...
const Rating = dynamic(import('components/Rating'));
...
```

I am using also jest-next-dynamic:

```
beforeAll(async () => {
  await preloadAll();
});
```

and then I am getting this:

Not supported
4 | import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

Any idea of what that could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by using "babel-plugin-transform-dynamic-import" package.

```
yarn add babel-plugin-transform-dynamic-import
```

and then I added this on *.babelrc*:

```
...
"plugins": [
  ["transform-dynamic-import"],
  ...
]
...
```

It solved my issues. Snapshot being generated properly again.